# FTP issue - FTP open Character encoding issue

Tags: 18.04, filezilla

FTP issue -   FTP open Character encoding issue

**local file name could not be decoded**

Ubuntu version : 18.04

FTP version  : 3.39.0

[image]

Comment: I feel as though you've been here long enough to know how to ask a proper question. http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 1):

Edit the **/etc/locale.gen** file, uncommenting the languages that you want to have in the system

```
sudo vim /etc/locale.gen
```

Then generate the files of each language with

```
sudo locale-gen
```

And finally make sure that your user has the variables "locale" that you need to the **.bash_profile** file.
For example English US:

```
echo "export LANGUAGE = en_US.UTF-8
export LANG = en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL = en_US.UTF-8 ">> ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be the old question but the below steps work for me when I faced the same problem on my Ubuntu 18.04

Step 1: Edit the Filezilla desktop file

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/filezilla.desktop
```

Step 2: Find the below line

```
Exec=filezilla
```

Step 3: Replace it with the below line

```
Exec=env LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 filezilla
```

Step 4: Save the file and exit the nano editor

Step 5: Close and reopen the filezilla app to see no errors related to `LC_CTYPE` or `LC_ALL` variable.